# Getting FileName and time taken in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have two questions here.

1) I'm trying to print the filename that i'm giving as input. But it is giving some random values.

```
set fileIn [open "[ pwd ]/Test - 2.csv" r]
puts "File Name : [file tail $fileIn]"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
File Name : file1d2d0a00
```

I came to know that i can use `[file tail "[ pwd ]/Test - 2.csv"]`. But can i do it from **fileIn**?

2) I'm trying to get the total time taken to run the script. I'm using below methods. It is giving me in milliseconds. How can i get it in Minutes?

```
set start_time [clock clicks -milliseconds]
{
# my operations
}
set time_taken [expr [clock clicks -milliseconds] - $start_time]
puts $time_taken
```

Other than using mathematical operations to convert, is there any inbuild methods(or other formats) are there to get the time in minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

Since you used the `open` command to read the file, the value returned by it will be nothing but a file pointer. i.e. a reference for file operations.  In order to get the file name you have use as follows,

```
set fileName "[pwd ]/Test - 2.csv"
puts "File Name : [file tail $fileName]";
# The variable 'fileIn' is the file pointer.
# You should use the same for further file operations.
set fileIn [open $fileName r]
```

**Question 2:**

To convert the milliseconds into minutes, you just have to divide the result by 60000.

```
set start_time [clock clicks -milliseconds]
# Your actions here
after 1000; # I just used 'after' command to sleep for 1s 
set time_taken [expr [clock clicks -milliseconds] - $start_time]
puts "time taken in milliseconds : $time_taken"
puts "time taken in seconds : [expr {[format "%#.10g" $time_taken]/1000}]"
puts "time taken in mins : [expr {[format "%#.10g" $time_taken]/60000}]"
```

**Output :**

```
time taken in milliseconds : 1011
time taken in seconds : 1.011
time taken in mins : 0.01685
```

Alternatively, you can use `[clock seconds]` to get time in seconds and divide that with 60 to get it in minutes.

Comment: Thanks Dinesh :) But here i'm reading the file and doing some operation, so i need to `open` the file. is there any way i can do it after Opening?